# Talend Open Studio line wrap causing sql statement invalid

Tags: talend

I am using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 6.2.1.
When using the component tPostgresqlRow, I entered sql statement in the query field of the component.

Sometimes the sql statement is too long and Talend automatically line wrap the statement. It will make the sql statement not executable.

How to disable line wrap in Talend Open Studio? Or is there another way to execute sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do not have reach the maximum sql statement length! 
So, as a work around, try to put your statement to a global variable, then use it in tPostgresqlInput.
Hop this helps.
TRF